# Get value in cell of HTML table with Razor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, razor

I have a table that looks like such:

```
<div style="float: left;">
  <table id="table_id">
    <thead style="background: #DAE6F0;">
      <th width="96">Action</th>
      <th width="110.5">Location</th>
      <th width="107">SelectionType</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model.List)
    {
      <tr>
        <td style="width: 49px; cursor: pointer"><a class="display" onclick=" getTeplate(@item.Id); ">Display</a></td>
        <td style="width: 49px; cursor: pointer"><a class="delete" onclick=" deleteTemplate(@item.Id); ">Delete</a></td>
        <td style="width: 120px; text-align: center">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AdvertisementLocation)</td>
        <td style="width: 107px; text-align: center">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AdvertisementSelectionType)</td>
      </tr>
    }
      </tbody>
  </table>
```

The first column displays the word "Display" which is a link that when clicked fires a function to get the contents of a template and display it. It does this by sending the Id to the function that is associated with that row. On load I populate a list with all the ads, and then foreach ad in the list a row is added to the table.

My question is how could I access the Id that is associated with the the Display column for that row with javascript. the work flow is a user can select an ad and edit it, upon update I refresh the page for the changes to be displayed in the table, and the table loads with row 1 in focus. I would would like to be able to focus the table on the row that had just been updated.